# How to create a table of outputs where inputs don't follow a simple pattern?

Tags: java

I'm not clear on how to make this table:

```
Number of |   Number of Services
 Agents   |    2       5       10
=====================================
    1     |        |       |
    2     |        |       |
    4     |        |       |
    8     |        |       |
   10     |        |       |
   12     |        |       |
```

I could +=2 but that would print for 6.
Other than typing all the values by hand.
using output from `Simulator.simulate(numServices, numAgents, 0.71, 15, 1200);`
I was thinking of using a two dimensional array to store outputs and another to store numServices and numAgents but I'm not clear on how to get it to work.

If I store it  as

```
int[6][3] in1 = {
  {2, 5, 10},
  {2, 5, 10},
  {2, 5, 10}
};
```

where do I store numAgents so that just by going from 1 to 6 I get their values?

```
printf("    1     |    %d     |   %d |   %d\n", r1[i][j], r1[i][j+1], r1[i][j+2]);
```

Comment: Java is an OO language. Use Objects to store your data.

Comment: You'll need to show more code than that.  Looks like you're possibly on the right track.

Comment: @JBNizet that was rather unhelpful

Comment: ?!  I do not understand what you are asking...can you break it down a little clearer, and remember that we are not privy to the system that you are writing so we do not know details unless you tell us.

Comment: The question is much too vague to be answered. But everytime I see a two-dimensional array, it could be replaced by some collection of objects. That makes more readable and maintainable code.

Comment: I just need to get a table and this is how I'm trying to save on writing the values by hand and calling the method for each. Just create the table.

Answer (score 0):

Every programmer is going to have a different way to do this.
The following is going to get you started.

```
public class DataElement {
    public DataElement(int nAgents, int nServices) {
        this.numberOfAgents = nAgents;
        this.numberOfServices = nServices;
    }
    // TODO Make private and use getters/setters
    int numberOfAgents;
    int numberOfServices;
    int resultInt;
    String resultString;
}

DataElement createElement(int numberOfAgents, int numberOfSerives) {
    return new DataElement(numberOfAgents, numberOfSerives);
}

void updateResult(DataElement dataElement, int resultInt, String resultString) {
    dataElement.resultInt = resultInt;
    dataElement.resultString = resultString;
}

void doCalculation(DataElement dataElement, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3 ){
}
```